# sqoop import direct table vs free form query

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to import data from the existing relational tables to hadoop environment using Sqoop 1.4.6.

When importing using free-form-query **--query** argument, all the columns in the specified table is fetched and written to a target directory successfully.

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x;database=yyyyy" \
--username xxxxxx --password yyyyyy \
--query 'SELECT * FROM tbltest WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--target-dir /user/hue/tbltest1 \
--fields-terminated-by '|'
--m 10
```

However, when I specify **--table** argument instead of free-form-query, the mapreduce job just hangs. I do not any exceptions or errors in map task logs either.

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x;database=yyyyy" \
--username xxxxxx --password yyyyyy \
--table tbltest \
--target-dir /user/hue/tbltest2 \
--fields-terminated-by '|'
--m 10

16/03/22 21:21:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1458667709298_0030
16/03/22 21:21:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1458667709298_0030 running in uber mode : false
16/03/22 21:21:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Can anyone point what exactly is the issue with the second method?

Comment: Please note that sql-server is only Microsoft SQL Server. this question is not related to it.

Comment: does your table 'tbltest' has primary key in it...?